# Flutter call RFlutter Alert from another class

Tags: flutter

I using flutter alert package rflutter_alert 1.1.0 , is it fine when writing the same code on same page. However due to many function making my code is too lengthy on 1 page.

So I try to split the alert function to another dart file, but I get the error of

```
A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be returned from method 'build' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.dart(return_of_invalid_type)
```

if I write like this

dialog dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

class Dialog extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogState createState() => _DialogState();
}

class _DialogState extends State<Dialog> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.error,
      title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
      desc: "Flutter testing Testing testing.",
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          child: Text(
            "COOL",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
          ),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          width: 120,
        )
      ],
    ).show();
  }
}
```

What is correct way to split out the rFlutter alert code and call it when press the button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`build` need a Widget no ant `Alert` , in order to call the alert but the code inside click callback (Button for example).

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FlatButton(onPressed: (){
        Alert(
          context: context,
          type: AlertType.error,
          title: "RFLUTTER ALERT",
          desc: "Flutter testing Testing testing.",
          buttons: [
            DialogButton(
              child: Text(
                "COOL",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              width: 120,
            )
          ],
        ).show();
      }, child: Text("CLICK ME!!")),
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks this work, how to make the DropdownButton inside this Alert to update the selection? Seem like the state inside the Alert is not updating, need close and open again the alert to update the state

Comment: It is better to open now question for this, but as a hint you have to use ```content``` param and pass ```StatefulWidget``` to it, and then you can manipulate the data inside it.